# bandwidth between the signal and the channel

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

I have a signal with a bandwidth $B=4$ kHz and the bandwitdh is between $6$ kHz and $10$ kHz. I want to transmit this signal in a channel with bandwidth $B'=4$ kHz but for the channel the bandwidth is between $1$ kHz and $5$ kHz.

This is my question:
Can we pass a signal in this channel even if the bandwidth support is not the same?

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't. But you mention a very specific signal bandwidth (4 kHz) and then a range (6 to 10 kHz). What is the actual signal bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like to pass a bandpass signal of 4Khz bandwidth in the frequency range 6 to 10 Khz, but you would like to transmit this directly over a channel which has good channel gain in 1 to 5Khz. Clearly, the signal when passed over a channel with this frequency response will suffer complete degradation.

Hence, we cannot transmit this signal directly over this channel. You could first downcovert the signal by 5 Khz and then transmit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can shift its spectrum to fit into the band of $[1k, 5k]$ Hz.

The following will do:
$$y(t) = \cos(2\pi ~5000~ t) \cdot x(t)$$

A new band of will appear at $[11k, 15k]$ Hz, that must either be filtered out by you before adding to the channel, or the channel itself will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your direct question is **no** because the channel will not pass the frequencies where the signal is.

To put in some practical sense, it will happen in the high frequency (HF = 3-30 MHz) regime where many factors affect whether or not certain frequencies propagate well. For example, a signal may propagate at a given frequency during the certain hours of the day, specific weather conditions, and even seasons.

This doesn't stop you from shifting your signal to a different frequency band though. For example, if your signal was shifted down to match the channel then you could transmit with (hopefully) only a small amount of attenuation given that you do a good job matching your signal bandwidth to the channel. The mathematical operation is laid out in @Fat32's answer.